# Vaadin Remove a record from database

Tags: java, vaadin

Could you give me a simple example on how to delete a record from my database using SQLContainer.

I have tried using `SQLContainer.Removeid(itemID)` but it still won't work. Hope someone can help me.

This is what I have tried:

```
try {
    SQLContainer DeleteContainer = new SQLContainer(new TableQuery("tbl_grade", connectionPool));
    Object ItemID = "10";
    DeleteContainer.removeItem(ItemID);
    DeleteContainer.commit();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it won't work? There appears to be plenty of examples online. Post your code.

Comment: try {
                        SQLContainer DeleteContainer = new SQLContainer(new TableQuery("tbl_grade", connectionPool));
                        Object ItemID = "10";
                        DeleteContainer.removeItem(ItemID);
                        DeleteContainer.commit();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

Comment: Should post any error messages or output that you get from your program as well. Please edit your Q and update it. Reading it from comments is more difficult.

Comment: There is no error message coming from the code. When i try the code nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `Id` of the item as an instance of `RowId` class.
Try this:
(Assumming `Id` of the item is of type `Integer`)

```
try {
    SQLContainer deleteContainer = new SQLContainer(new TableQuery("tbl_grade", connectionPool));
    RowId itemID = new RowId(new Integer[] { 10 });
    deleteContainer.removeItem(itemID);
    deleteContainer.commit();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```